# Collapsing spectral sequence

Tags: homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

In Weibel's definition of a homology spectral sequence collapsing at $E^r$ he says that if it converges to $H_*$ then $H_n$ is the unique non zero $E_{pq}^r$ such that $p+q=n$. I am trying to prove it but so far, I haven't been able to go very far, I am trying to use the fact that $E_{pq}^\infty\cong F_pH_n/F_{p-1}H_n$ but I haven't been really successful and I don't have any idea on how to see that. Does anyone have any help for me?

Comment: Please clarify how the spectral sequence is setup and what your notation means (what's $H_n$? What's $E_{pq}$ (no superscript)? etc.).

Comment: @BenSteffan I edited it, hope it's more clear with the proper statement

Comment: I have my doubts that this is all of the context. For one, the statement as you give it is wrong: There are spectral sequences that collapse on the $E^2$-page but for which more than one $E^r_{p, q}$ with $p + q = n$ is non-zero (this happens in the Serre spectral sequence $E^2_{p, q} = H_p(S^7; H^q(U(3); \mathbb{Z})) \Rightarrow H_{p + q}(U(4); \mathbb{Z})$ for instance on the $p + q = 8$ antidiagonal; I'm sorry that I don't have a more accessible counterexample :/).

Comment: Look at the group extension $1 \to C_2 \to C_2 \times C_2 \to C_2 \to 1$ and the spectral sequence computing group homology with $\mathbb{F}_2$ coefficients. This collapses at $E^2$, and $E^2_{1,0}$ and $E^2_{0,1}$ are both nonzero. Or look at the Serre spectral sequence for the homology of the product $S^2 \times S^2$, viewed as a trivial fibration $S^2 \to S^2 \times S^2 \to S^2$.

Comment: @BenSteffan check for yourself Definition 5.2.7 https://math.mit.edu/~hrm/palestine/weibel/05-spectral_sequences.pdf

Comment: @Jolia "A (homology) spectral sequence _collapses_ at $E^r$ ($r \geq 2$) if there is exactly one nonzero row or column in the lattice $\{E^r_{pq}\}$" That's exactly why I asked you to provide more context, because this is **not the standard definition**, at least nowadays: To me (and John (as it seems), and everybody I know) a spectral sequence collapses at the $r$th page if there are no non-trivial differentials $d_k$ for all $k \geq r$.

Comment: @BenSteffan Oh okay I get it now, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I've managed to find the answer: Since $E_{p,q}^r\neq 0$ for only one index $p_0$ then consider a filtration
$$0=F_sH_n \subseteq \ldots \subseteq F_{p_0}H_n \subseteq \ldots \subseteq F_tH_n=H_n.$$
By assumption for all $(p,q)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $n=p+q$, we have
$$E_{p,q}^\infty\cong F_pH_n/F_{p-1}H_n$$
Now this implies that $F_{s+1}H_n/F_sH_n\simeq E_{s,q}^\infty=0$ hence $F_{s+1}H_n=0$. By induction, we show that for $k\in[|s;p_0-1|]$, $F_kH_n=0$. Now we have $E_{p_0,q}^\infty\cong F_{p_0}H_n$ and $E_{p_0+1,q}^\infty\cong F_{p_0+1}H_n/F_{p_0}H_n$ hence $F_{p_0+1}H_n\simeq E_{p_0,q}^\infty$ and we show that it is the case for all $k\in[|p_0;t|]$. This shows that the term $F_tH_n=H_n\cong E_{p_0,q}^\infty$ which is said non zero term.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some authors use the verb "degenerate" to mean that the spectral sequence has no further nonzero differentials at that page or later, reserving "collapse" as given here; with these senses, "collapse" is stronger than "degenerate". Others use "collapse" to mean just the first, weaker, notion. To give one illustration, I think of nLab is pretty reliable, but see Examples 3.4 and 3.5 on the page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spectral+sequence+of+a+filtered+complex. Since the term "collapse" is ambiguous, maybe we should all avoid it and/or spell out exactly what we mean when we use it. (In contrast, saying that a spectral sequence "degenerates at the $E_r$-page" is not, I think ambiguous.)